# Tkinter GUI for caesar cipher doesn't work as intended

Tags: python, tkinter, caesar-cipher

I made a tkinter GUI for the caesar cipher program but it doesn't work properly.
I type my message in the first entry box, enter the key in the second one, then click encrypt/decrypt, and the result shows up in the third entry box. But i never get the correct results.

Also sometimes if i use a key that is higher than 6, or enter multiple words, i get the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:/Users/PC/PycharmProjects/oyun/sezarUIing.py", line 33, in Encrypt
self.translation = self.translation + self.LETTERS[sayı]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Sezar(Frame):
    def __init__(self,pencere):
        Frame.__init__(self,pencere)
        self.pencere = pencere

        self.Lab1 = Label(pencere, text="Enter your message: ",relief= GROOVE, width=20).place(x=20,y=30)

        self.Lab2 = Label(pencere, text="Enter key: ", relief=GROOVE, width=20).place(x=20, y=90)

        self.Ent1 = Entry(pencere,width=30)
        self.Ent1.place(x=170,y=30)

        self.Ent2 = Entry(pencere,width=30)
        self.Ent2.place(x=170,y=90)

        self.But1 = Button(pencere, text="Encrypt", relief=GROOVE,font="bold",command= self.Encrypt).place(x=50,y=150)
        self.But1 = Button(pencere, text="Decrypt", relief=GROOVE, font="bold",command= self.Decrypt).place(x=110, y=150)

        self.RESULT = Entry(pencere, width=30)
        self.RESULT.place(x=170,y=200)

        self.LETTERS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        self.translation = ""


    def Encrypt(self):
        for num in self.Ent1.get():
            if num in self.LETTERS:
                sayı = self.LETTERS.find(num)
                sayı = sayı + int(self.Ent2.get())
                self.translation = self.translation + self.LETTERS[sayı]
                self.RESULT.insert(0,self.translation)
            else:
                self.translation = self.translation + num


    def Decrypt(self):
        for num in self.Ent1.get():
            if num in self.LETTERS:
                sayı = self.LETTERS.find(num)
                sayı = sayı - int(self.Ent2.get())
                if sayı >= 0:
                    sayı = sayı - len(self.LETTERS)
                elif sayı <= 0:
                    sayı = sayı + len(self.LETTERS)
                self.translation = self.translation + self.LETTERS[sayı]
                self.RESULT.insert(0,self.translation)
            else:
                self.translation = self.translation + num

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Sezar")
    root.geometry("400x300+50+50")
    Sezar(root).pack(side="top",fill = "both")
    root.mainloop()
```

He is an example of the error and what is expected

Example of the error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H0xO.png)

Intended result: [Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuaKn.png)

Comment: Have you looked at the other 100+ "caesar cipher doesn't work" questions and answers on SO? They all come down to the same thing.

Comment: @zaph I have. However I could not find anyone that is using tkinter having the same problem as me

Comment: Have you tried taking tkinter out of the equation until you get the encryption/decryption working, so that you know where the problem actually lies?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley Yes i have, the original program is working fine. But it wasn't object oriented, so the problem might have something to do with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message was due to you not using modular arithmetic in your `Encrypt()` method (you had implemented such in your `Decrypt()` method.)

Other problems include not clearing `self.RESULT` before adding new text; not clearing `self.translation` before appending the results from a new translation; not controlling letter case; not updating `self.RESULT` at an appropriate place in your code (if text ends in a number, it's not reflected in the translation).

Below's my rework of your code addressing the above issues:

```
from tkinter import *

class Sezar(Frame):
    LETTERS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    def __init__(self, pencere):
        Frame.__init__(self, pencere)
        self.pencere = pencere

        Label(pencere, text="Enter your message: ", relief=GROOVE, width=20).place(x=20, y=30)
        self.Ent1 = Entry(pencere, width=30)
        self.Ent1.place(x=170, y=30)

        Label(pencere, text="Enter key: ", relief=GROOVE, width=20).place(x=20, y=90)
        self.Ent2 = Entry(pencere, width=30)
        self.Ent2.place(x=170, y=90)

        Button(pencere, text="Encrypt", relief=GROOVE, font="bold", command=self.Encrypt).place(x=50, y=150)
        Button(pencere, text="Decrypt", relief=GROOVE, font="bold", command=self.Decrypt).place(x=110, y=150)

        self.RESULT = Entry(pencere, width=30)
        self.RESULT.place(x=170, y=200)

    def Encrypt(self):
        key = int(self.Ent2.get())
        length = len(self.LETTERS)

        translation = ''

        for character in self.Ent1.get():
            if character.lower() in self.LETTERS:
                sayı = self.LETTERS.find(character.lower())
                sayı = (sayı + key) % length
                translation += self.LETTERS[sayı]
            else:
                translation += character

        self.RESULT.delete(0, END)
        self.RESULT.insert(0, translation)

    def Decrypt(self):
        key = int(self.Ent2.get())
        length = len(self.LETTERS)

        translation = ''

        for character in self.Ent1.get():
            if character.lower() in self.LETTERS:
                sayı = self.LETTERS.find(character.lower())
                sayı = (sayı - key) % length
                translation += self.LETTERS[sayı]
            else:
                translation += character

        self.RESULT.delete(0, END)
        self.RESULT.insert(0, translation)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Sezar")
    root.geometry("400x300+50+50")
    Sezar(root).pack(side="top", fill="both")
    root.mainloop()
```